# Where can I find a list of StackOverflow MUST READ beginner related advice questions?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Where can I find a list of StackOverflow **must read beginner related advice** questions?

**EDIT:What kind of advice(not books) from experienced programmers i should keep in mind before thinking of becoming a software developer**

It is a big problem for me (or beginners) because I don't know what I need to know.

Here is an example of a couple posts that would be on this list:

> - [What books should I read to have an undergraduate education in Computer Science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143760/)
> - [How to find a mentor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94579/)
> - [What are the best RSS feeds for programmers/developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119/)

What type of tags (other than beginner) should I be looking at while searching?
Should I sort by number of votes?

Comment: SackOverflow?

Comment: @RichB looks like you need to learn spellings

Comment: @Rishi: I wouldn't be casting stones from inside that glass house of yours.

Comment: Stick to a question. Stop moving the goal posts every time you get an answer or a comment that you don't agree with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So wait... You don't know what you need to know, so you want a list of things to read that will help you to learn. But you *also* don't know what you want to accomplish, so you want a *list of lists* of things to read for every possible goal, so that you can read through all of them?

Seems like it'd be simpler just to pick a topic that interests you and... search for a list covering that topic.

---

After reading your comments, I think you're trying to jump past the "learning to walk" stage of programming. **Don't**. Blogs, career advice, and CS theory are all fun to read, and will eventually be useful to you as a working programmer... But first, you really need to get comfortable **just writing code**. Making the computer do what you tell it. Finding out why it doesn't when it doesn't. **Learning how to *read*** (rather than decipher) other people's code, how to ask questions of it, and where to look for answers to those questions. Taking what you learn writing one program and putting it to use when writing another. Coming to the realization that your code, like everything else you write, is ultimately disposable. At that point, the essays you read on blogs, and the axioms you read in books will no longer be merely lists that you must commit to memory, but sensible conclusions that fit into your own experience (or ridiculous blather that you can dismiss outright...)

I'm not trying to be obstinate or unhelpful here, and i doubt anyone else is either... But there's a limited utility in throwing ever-longer lists at someone still beginning the long, long study that you are. When you reach the point where you could make use of a real answer to this question, chances are you'll no longer need it...

Comment: Just the very basics of programming like the examples highlighted in the question

Comment: @Rishi: How about you read a book then?

Comment: So search for that: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beginner+programmer+reading

Comment: @TheTXI I just rephrased the question to get an answer as i realized that beginner covers a lot of stuff. Also i wanted to add the links to the questions here if thats ok

Comment: @Rishi: You made the question into a different question. That is not ok here.

Comment: Advice is what i wanted i meant but poor english(totally my fault) lead to the debate

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a list of these questions needs to exist. Just search for what you need, and ask for anything that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the rephrase but don't know what I need to know.

Comment: First, you must know what you wish to do.

Comment: @Rishi: Then you are not going very far anyway. Read through the tags you are interested in. This is a Q&A site, not a 'learn programming in 24 hours' site.

Comment: Be a good programmer, i don't know how to define that

Comment: So search for *that* then: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+a+good+programmer

Comment: @Rishi: Then go to school.

Comment: I found about stackoverflow a few months ago, i am very much interested in programming i just don't know how do i develop my skills, I found lots of valuable advice on SO , but its all very fragmented which is fine but a list of questions will suffice

Comment: Some type of tags i should be looking at or no of votes while searching?

Comment: @rishi: If you don't have the ability to learn on your own, I recommend you try going to college. They will teach you how to learn there.

Comment: @Rishi: you don't need a list - just search! The built-in search routine will generate more lists than you'll ever be able to process, for any question you could possibly come up with, faster than i can type a single link.

Comment: @Shog9: But he doesn't want to learn, he wants you to teach him!

Comment: About the "go to school" comment, I am in an undergraduate CS course, but in my country(India) there are a handful of good schools(IITs etc) and I did't make it there.

Comment: @Rishi: You need to learn how to learn before you learn how to program. From the question you are asking, I don't believe you understand how to learn yet.

Comment: I imagine there is much snatching of pebbles from blind men's hands.

Comment: Please try to understand the technological & cultural disparity, The concept of blogs & internet as a medium was (as is still to many) foreign to me.

Comment: I learned about lifehacker in may ,readwriteweb in june , Joelonsoftware in july (I read every single article he has written in 2 weeks),

Comment: I got to know about Eric Raymond a week ago (the open source guy), and then about the halloween documents which are very interesting to know about the open source movement & microsoft

Comment: @Rishi: No one cares what you know about the internet. You don't seem to understand how to learn. You need to learn how to learn before anyone can help you.

Comment: @Rishi: i get the feeling you're trying to do the programming equivalent of learning to run before you can walk. Start simple. Use search - on SO and on Google - to find the answers to any questions that come up. Write as much code as you can. **Make as many mistakes as you can, *and learn from them*.** The more you learn, the better you'll get at coming up with questions to ask, and the better you'll get at finding answers to them.

Comment: OK how do i learn how to learn (other then school)

Comment: @Rishi: This is not the site for that. I recommend you pay attention at college though.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for trying to understand me

Comment: @RichB I thought this was the site for good developers/programmers and was confident of getting guided, seems like you are only interested in answering the coding questions and not the rest of the Software Engineering part

Comment: Let me also tell you that my school's primary aim is to get us employed in the glorious Indian Consulting Industry

Comment: here's the kicker : Without teaching us how to write code.

Comment: @Rishi: SO.com is not an education Q&A site. It is a programming Q&A site.

Comment: The point is that you educate yourself or copy/paste the code in the answers

Comment: Okay, how about you guide me with your Knowledge.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308284/advice-for-beginners-eclipse-web-application

Comment: @Rishi: No, I won't. I have no interest in your question. But the other 30k+ users might be. That is kind of the idea.

Comment: Then stop commenting :) Someone more interested will come along to help me. I get that all the time, people who tell me what i am doing wrong but never bother to tell me how to do it right

Comment: @Rishi: You asked the question. I answered. That is what we do here.

Comment: Also disrespecting me by calling me unable to learn in short stupid.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs

Comment: @Rishi: That is not disrespectful. It is the truth.

Comment: @Rishi: i've worked with people in... the Glorious Indian Consulting Industry - i know where you're coming from. And, trust me, the two best things you can learn are *how to identify what you don't know* about a problem, and *how to find answers to the questions that crop up while you're coding*. These two skills effectively separate the code monkeys from the programmers, and you really can't fake it. Good luck...

Comment: i meant that as sarcasm - Glorious Indian Consulting Industry

Comment: my initial question was what kind of advice(not books) from experienced programmers i should keep in mind before thinking of becoming a software developer

Comment: @Rishi: no worries, i got it... ;-)

As for the advice... Look, there are plenty of people willing to write about this stuff, and they *do* write about it, more than anyone could read in a lifetime. Most of it isn't worth reading, and what's left *still* isn't worth reading unless you have a foundation for it to build on. This is probably my biggest problem with the "beginner list" questions on SO: they're great for non-beginners to commiserate with each other on articles that they agree with, but often so far beyond what any real beginner can understand as to be useless. **Start simple.**

Comment: Please add it to your answer

Comment: @Shog9 after reading joelonsoftware (every single article) what would you suggest

Comment: If you enjoyed those, then read them again, slowly, and every time you encounter a reference to a book, find it and read it, or find and read similar essays. Every time you find a reference to a blog you haven't read, read it. Every time you encounter a reference to an unfamiliar programming concept, search for and find a good reference for it, read the code illustrating it until you understand it, then practice using it.

Answer (score 0):

Getting started in programming is hard and it is difficult to come up to speed on topics when you do not know the lingo. Programming jargon is very important because words like "encapsulates," "object-oriented" and "debug" represent complex ideas which are central to the art.

You are not going to find a list of lists because it is impractical to try to create and maintain such a thing. Instead, take some time to learn how to use StackOverflow's tag system. By going to the tag section and searching for things like "beginner" you get 2 tags. When you click the first tag (Beginner) you get a list of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner).

Look through those search results and read the first question you understand. Then look at the words you don't understand in the accepted or highest voted response. Search StackOVerflow or Google for those words and learn their meaning.

After a while you'll figure out what it is you do not know, then you can move on to learning how to fill those gaps.

Comment: I am not talking about actual coding

Comment: *facepalm*

Comment: @Rishi: Good, then search for "How to ask a question".

Comment: ...Ow      my face.